# What are these directories and files in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, zxcvbn

Whilst looking for something else entirely, i stumbled across these, in Chrome's Application Support folder.

```
# syh @ h in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/ZxcvbnData/1 [21:07:42]
$ l
total 1592
drwx------@ 11 syh  staff   352B Dec 19 21:06 .
drwx------@  3 syh  staff    96B Dec 19 21:06 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 syh  staff    66B Oct 11 10:56 manifest.fingerprint
drwx------@  3 syh  staff    96B Oct 11 10:56 _metadata
-rw-------@  1 syh  staff   166B Oct 11 10:56 manifest.json
-rw-------@  1 syh  staff   271K Oct 11 10:56 english_wikipedia.txt
-rw-------@  1 syh  staff    26K Oct 11 10:56 female_names.txt
-rw-------@  1 syh  staff   6.5K Oct 11 10:56 male_names.txt
-rw-------@  1 syh  staff   236K Oct 11 10:56 passwords.txt
-rw-------@  1 syh  staff    74K Oct 11 10:56 surnames.txt
-rw-------@  1 syh  staff   160K Oct 11 10:56 us_tv_and_film.txt
```

It looks like some data that is being used by [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn), which Chrome might be using. Does anyone know what Chrome is using this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was tracked in Chromium bug [1104878 - Passwords: Add zxcvbn-cpp as third_party library](https://crbug.com/1104878).

> This issue serves as a tracking bug to add zxcvbn-cpp [1] as a third_party library to Chromium. It is intended to be used for realistic password strength estimation within the Password Manager component.
>
> [1] https://github.com/rianhunter/zxcvbn-cpp